# Using Anaconda - Can import numpy into Jupyterlab but not Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

Absolute newbie using Anaconda in Windows to launch apps. I can run this code successfully in JupyterLabs within either notebooks or console and also runs fine in Spyder, but I get an error running in Pycharm:

```
    import numpy as np

    weights = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0])

    def neural_network(input, weights):
        pred = input.dot(weights)
        return pred

    toes = np.array([8.5, 9.5, 9.9, 9.0])
    wlrec = np.array([0.65, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9])
    nfans = np.array([1.2, 1.3, 0.5, 1.0])

    input = np.array([toes[0], wlrec[0], nfans[0]])
    pred = neural_network(input, weights)

    print(pred)
```

I get following error msg:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

What do I need to check to see why I have access to this library in JupyterLabs but not PyCharm even though both are launched from my Anaconda dashboard?  I can import re just fine.

Comment: Check the Python interpreter in PyCharm. Maybe you’re not using conda virtual environment. If this is the case, change the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm, you'll need to set the environment you're using, so that it sees your already installed packages.
If you open the settings in PyCharm, you'll see the menu item starting with `Project: ...`. Under that, go to `Project Interpreter` and add a new environment. This should be the folder where Anaconda is installed for you (by default it's `C:\Users\<your-username>\Anaconda3\`)

So the Python executable you're looking for would be in `C:\Users\<your-username>\Anaconda3\bin\python` in that case - this can differ depending on where you installed Anaconda.

Answer (score -1):

you need to install numpy in pycharm, see [userguide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: Worked like a "charm".  Thank you for the link to the specific page and screen shots.

Comment: and @JG  I am too new, I don't have enough reputation points to change the counter.  I have upvoted both your answers, and do not know who downvoted you.  I got the answer I needed and am very grateful.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install `numpy` into the environment you are using by either `pip install numpy` or `conda install numpy`, also see https://numpy.org/install/

Comment: Thank you. You were correct, but I was too new to programming to know where to look becasue I didn't even know the term I needed to look up was to install a *package*  LOL  

Thank you and @gftea for taking pity